# Which programming language is Curiosity written in?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Mars Curiosity Rover's software built in?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159637/what-is-the-mars-curiosity-rovers-software-built-in)

I only recently came across an article that stated there was well over 500,000 lines of code in Curiosity and I was very much intrigued; which language did NASA use and what computer and CPU architecture has Curiosity got on-board; would they have reused Space Shuttle code and hardware?
I know it has to be a low level language such a C/C++ and or assembly, but they might have a specialised use that doesn't fit with these languages.
Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Already asked here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159637/what-is-the-mars-curiosity-rovers-software-built-in